# How to set value to NULL in my dropdown list?

Tags: java, html, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a dropdown list of users that I can assign to a **WorkOrder**. Where User to WorkOrder is a OneToMany relationship.  The problem is how to assign a NULL value to a **user Id** ? If I don't set it to NULL it works fine and I can assign any name from the list.

If I use this code and pick NULL `<form:option value="${null}" label="null" />` in my jsp i get an error:

`Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property user.id; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Here's my **WorkorderDAOImpl**

```
    @Override
public void saveWorkOrder(WorkOrder theWorkOrder) {

    // get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    User user = theWorkOrder.getUser();
    System.out.println("workorder: " + theWorkOrder);
    System.out.println("user: " + user);

    //save/update the work order
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theWorkOrder);


}
```

My workorder-form.jsp I omitted some of the labels

```
    <form:errors path="workorder.*"/>
    <form:errors path="user.*"/>

<form:form action="saveWorkOrder" modelAttribute="workorder" method="POST">

    <!-- need to assotiate the data with workorder id -->
    <form:hidden path="id"/>


    <table>
        <tbody>


            <tr>
                <td><label>User name:</label></td>
                <td><form:input path="user.userName"/></td>


            </tr>

            <tr>

            <td><label>User:</label></td>
                <td><form:select path="user.id">
                    <form:option value="${null}" label="null" />
                    <form:options items="${users}" 
                 itemLabel="userName" itemValue="id"  
                    />

                    </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `int` in Java cannot be `NULL` so changed my `id` from int to `Integer`. Integer can be null. 
I also added an `if` statement to my WorkOrderDAOImpl.java to check if user.id was set to null.

Here's my updated code.

```
    @Override
public void saveWorkOrder(WorkOrder theWorkOrder) {
    System.out.println(" \n Printing from WorkOrder : \n");
    // get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    User user = theWorkOrder.getUser();

    if (user.getId() == null) {

        theWorkOrder.setUser(null);
    }

    //save/update the work order
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theWorkOrder);


}
```